# Automations need "jump start" after import

Tags: automation, oracle-apex

my automations remain active, but not working after export/import. So I have to execute them manually, only for that one time after importing them. Otherwise they just wait.

it's probably the expected behaviour for some security measures. But is there a way to alter it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour because an automation could potentially do something very destructive and if it was enabled by default on import a lot of damage could be done. There are a couple of ways to tackle this.

- For some admin-type applications I have an alert region that shows the status of the automation and the option to enable/disable it.
- It is also a good practice to bundle the automations in their own application that  has no functionality other than the automations. That way when any of the main applications are overwritten by an import the automations are not affected.